# Was the Paschal Offering roasted with or without the sciatic nerve and chelev?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, passover, korban

Do the sources describe removing (nikkur/taber) the gid hanasheh (sciatic nerve) and chelev (forbidden fats) from the Pashcal Offering when it was roasted whole?  If not, would cooking the sciatic nerve and chelev render the hindquarters or the whole animal non-kosher?

How does one get the chelev out of the insides of the carcass without breaking bones?

(The process is described [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Vew7wFdPgo)): .

Answer (score 9):

This is a Korban, so the Chelev was burned on the Mizbeach.

Regarding the Gid haNasheh, there is a famous disagreement between the Rambam and the Raavad (Korban Pesach 10:11):

> כשאדם אוכל את הפסח חותך הבשר ואוכל וחותך העצמות מן הפרק ומפרקן אם רצה. וכשיגיע לגיד הנשה מוציאו ומניחו עם שאר הגידים והעצמות והקרומות שיוצאין בשעת אכילה. שאין מנקין אותו כשאר הבשר ואין מחתכין אותו אלא צולין אותו שלם.‏
>
> **א"א** 
>   *בחיי ראשי אין איסור גדול מזה שיצלה הפסח עם גיד הנשה ועם שמנו ועם תרבא דתותי מתנא ועם קרומות שבראש ואם אזכה ואוכל פסח ויביא לפני כזה הייתי חובטו בקרקע לפניו:*   ‏
>
> When a person eats the Pesach he cuts the meat and eats, and cuts the bones at the joints and splits them if he wants. And when he arrives at the Gid haNasheh he removes it and places it with the other sinews, bones and membranes which are removed while eating. For we don't clean [the Pesach] like ordinary meat and we don't cut it, rather we roast it whole.
>
> *Said [Ra]A[VaD]: In the life of my head there is no greater prohibition than this that one would roast the Pesach with the Gid haNasheh and its [surrounding fats and other prohibited membranes], and if I merit and eat a Pesach and he brings before me like that I would throw it on the ground in front of him.*  (my translation)

As for why the Rambam holds it's ok, see the commentaries there for various possibilities, but the simplest answer is the Gid haNasheh doesn't have any flavor so it can't prohibit the surrounding meat and the fats around the Gid haNasheh are only prohibited as a custom.

Comment: The gid hanashe has no flavour?? That's contrary to what it says in Hullin 7:4-5, which speaks of the possibility of נותן טעם. Is that speaking of something else? I only know those mishnayes, not the gemara (+1 by the way)

Comment: @ShimonbM It's a Machloket Tannaim whether יש בגידין בנותן טעם or אין בגידין בנותן טעם. See the Gemara there, or Pesachim 22a, or probably a few other places. Without making too strong a statment, "we" seem to generally hold there is no flavor.

Comment: How does one get the chelev out of the insides of the carcass without breaking bones?

Comment: @yehu The abdomen, seemingly. Bone marrow isn't Chelev. What's the problem?

Comment: Perhaps you are right. Perhaps it is possible to have physical and visual access to the innards of the carcass through the abdomen.  But it would seem that such access would make the removal process much harder. The video shows how hard it is now.

Comment: In any case, were the rear quarters removed (which would seem to require cutting the spinal cord, or were they left intact, which would seem to run the risk of cooking the chelev and gid h.

Comment: @YehudaW The rear quarters were not removed, just the innards removed. More specifics I can't provide you here, and anyone providing them in text is going to find it quite challenging to do so. If you're looking for videos of Nikkur from Temple times, they are unfortunately unavailable. This is as good as I can do right now. I hope you've found it helpful.