Is it permissible for a rabbi to publicly criticize and insult other rabbis who he finds to be misguiding the community and misrepresenting Judaism?
I've seen certain rabbis do this to other rabbis and even encourage their students and followers to do the same. Is this allowed in Judaism?

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/78213/759

@DoubleAA I take it from that passage that it's permissible?
